# Setting ThreadContext for all threads in application

Tags: java, multithreading, log4j, log4j2

From this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/25125159/4367326 I have `routingAppender` working but I want to set the `ThreadContext` for every thread in the program.

When I set

```
ThreadContext.put("logFileName", "TestLogFile");
```

it works for the main thread and logs as expected but not for any other threads in my application. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Every child thread will inherit fathers ThreadContext state if you set up system property **isThreadContextMapInheritable** to true. But this will not work for Executors so you need to manually copy data from one thread to another.

**Update#2**

You can do something like this:

```
public abstract class ThreadContextRunnable implements Runnable {

  private final Map context = ThreadContext.getContext();

  @Override
  public final void run() {
    if (context != null) {
      ThreadContext.putAll(context);
    }
    try {
      runWithContext();
    } finally {
      ThreadContext.clearAll();
    }
  }

  protected abstract void runWithContext();
}
```

And then you only need to implement runWithContext method.

Comment: For Executors can I set the ThreadContext in the run() of the class they call for all of the executors children?