# Spring Integration inbound-gateway how to save soap request to file?

Tags: web-services, spring-integration, inbound

In Spring Integration, using inbound-gateway, do you know how to save each SOAP WS Request to separated files ?

Currently, I stuck at:

```
<!-- inbound -->
<ws:inbound-gateway id="inbound-gateway" request-channel="SOAPRequestChannel" reply-channel="SOAPResponseChannel"/>
<int:channel id="SOAPRequestChannel">
    <int:interceptors>
        <int:wire-tap channel="SOAPRequestChannelForLog"/>
    </int:interceptors>
</int:channel>
<int:channel id="SOAPResponseChannel" />
<int:channel id="SOAPRequestChannelForLog" />   

<int:logging-channel-adapter id="logger" expression="payload" level="INFO" channel="SOAPRequestChannelForLog"/>
```

But it just log all requests in 1 file.

OR I have to write another class like LogToFile which has a method to save that request to file, replace int:logging-channel-adapter with int:service-activator ?  Does Spring support out-of-the-box logging each SOAP request ? I read the reference document, but couldn't find any thing.

OR there is any better way ? ^_^

Regards,

Comment: I found out Spring support PayloadLoggingInterceptor & SoapEnvelopeLoggingInterceptor by reading the book Spring Web Service 2 Cookbook at first, then check the reference document. It is there ^_^

Comment: Please, form a proper answer to the question and accept it. That will help other people to find a solution and the question will disappear from my dashboard. Or just remove it :-)

Comment: Hi @Artem Bilan, actually, it is not the solution yet as PayloadLoggingInterceptor use log4j2 to log the payload. Currently, I don't know how to configure log4j2 to log each request/response separately. Anyway, I put an temporary answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all `PayloadLoggingInterceptor` is based on the `org.apache.commons.logging.Log` and that is already your application responsibility which target logging system to use. Yes, Log4j2 is one of them. There is only just need to have a proper bridge from Commons Logging to the target impl. Looks like it is out-of-the-box for Log4j...

If you want to store each request to its own file, consider to use [`<int-file:outbound-channel-adapter>`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/files.html) for that purpose.

You just need to build a proper content based on the incoming Message:

```
Transformer transformer = createNonIndentingTransformer();
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
transformer.transform(source, new StreamResult(writer));
String message = writer.toString();
```

Where `source` is a `payload` of the message after `<ws:inbound-gateway>`.

And you will just need to figure out the `file name` based on that message or some other environment.

Comment: oh, I didn't know there is int-file:outbound-channel ^ _ ^

Comment: Converted `int-file:outbound-channel-adapter` to the link for its documentation

Answer (score 1):

I found out Spring support PayloadLoggingInterceptor & SoapEnvelopeLoggingInterceptor by reading the book Spring Web Service 2 Cookbook at first, then check the reference document. It is there ^

I will combine with how to log4j2 log to separated files as describe here
[Log4j2: How to write logs to separate files for each user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25114526/log4j2-how-to-write-logs-to-separate-files-for-each-user)